# Best practices for writing / debugging complex PL/pgSQL queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, procedural-programming

**In short:** What is the best way to write and debug PostgreSQL queries that make use of procedural programming techniques (e.g. using pl/pgsql)? I'm pretty new to writing these types of procedural queries so apologies in advance if there is a really simple solution I haven't found.

**Specifics:** I am writing some (relatively) complex SQL queries that make use of existing pl/pgsql functions and ideally would make use of lots of variables to make the query easy to debug and modify. (The example code below is deliberately simple; my actual use cases are much more complicated.)

My first solution was to embed everything inside a function, but this is clunky. Since I have to declare the return type explicitly, it makes modifying the code a pain:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
my_schema.my_fcn()
RETURNS TABLE(user_id integer, 
              id integer, 
              created_at timestamp) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _id_select integer = 10;
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            id,
            created_at
        WHERE id = _id_selector
        -- possibly a ton of other complicated stuff involving other functions and variables
        FROM my_schema.my_other_fcn()

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(Edit: Made the query slightly more nontrivial.)

Now suppose I want to add `order_total` to my query and get rid of `id`: Then I have to modify the return type. This is going to happen a lot, and its annoying to have to change the return type over and over.

The next solution I tried was to NOT use a function, and try something along these lines: [How can I execute pl/pgsql code without creating a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569504/how-can-i-execute-pl-pgsql-code-without-creating-a-function)
This does not work either:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    _id_select integer = 10;
BEGIN
  SELECT 
      user_id, 
      id,
      created_at
  WHERE id = _id_selector
  -- possibly a ton of other complicated stuff involving other functions and variables
  FROM my_schema.my_other_fcn()
END $$;
```

The resulting error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: query has no destination for result data
```

I do not want to use `PERFORM` because, actually, I do want to see the result of the query.

Is there a graceful and/or standard solution to this type of SQL programming?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't call plpgsql function directly?

do only:

```
 SELECT 
      user_id, 
      id,
      created_at
  -- possibly a ton of other complicated stuff involving other functions and variables
  FROM my_schema.my_other_fcn()
```

I don't like a this style of plpgsql programming - wrapping queries. You can block very effective planner - because plpgsql function is black box for optimizer - so you can expect terrible performance issues on large data. PLpgSQL functions should not to substitute a views.

Statement DO should not to return any result. Simply - PostgreSQL functions should not to substitute PostgreSQL views.

Comment: Calling the embedded function directly as a query like this does not (as far as I know) allow you to use variables, loops, etc. in the query. This is what was intended by the `-- possibly a ton of other complicated stuff involving other functions and variables`. Regarding performance, this is not a concern for me in this context.

Comment: if you need a variables, loops and possible returns, then you need to use functions - DO statement is too limited - and there are not any other possibility.