# Can I count on a simple case/switch plpgsql function to use a sane query plan?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to implement a postgres function with optional parameters.  The way that I have gone about this is to implement stable sql functions with *required* parameters, and then I delegate to those depending on a simple IF/ELSEIF case chain.

Here is a simplified example:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tab1(
    field1 int PRIMARY KEY,
    field2 int
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tab2(
    field1 int PRIMARY KEY,
    field2 int
);
INSERT INTO test_tab1 SELECT FLOOR(RANDOM()*10000), FLOOR(RANDOM()*10000) FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,10);
INSERT INTO test_tab2 SELECT * FROM test_tab1;
    
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_tab1_func()
    RETURNS SETOF test_tab1
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE 
    AS $$
        SELECT * FROM test_tab1;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_tab2_func()
    RETURNS SETOF test_tab1
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE 
    AS $$
        SELECT * FROM test_tab2;
$$;
```

The function that is the subject of my question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(foo int DEFAULT null)
    RETURNS SETOF test_tab1
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE 
    AS $$
        BEGIN
            IF (foo IS null) THEN
                RETURN QUERY
                SELECT * FROM test_tab1_func();
            ELSE
                RETURN QUERY
                SELECT * FROM test_tab2_func();
            END IF;
        END;
$$;

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test_func();
```

This `EXPLAIN` returns:

```
Function Scan on test_func  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=8)
```

My experiments with more complex queries show that this `Function Scan` estimate is not very "smart", and will return basically this same result no matter the complexity of the function body.  Since the `EXPLAIN` output is so uninformative, I have come here for more info on the execution plan.

My question is this:  Since the DB presumably can plan for `test_tab1_func`, and it can plan for `test_tab2_func`, can I count on the DB to use the plan that it would ordinarily devise for `test_tab1_func` for `test_func` when `foo` is `null`, and the plan that it would ordinarily devise for `test_tab2_func` for `test_func` otherwise?  If not, is there a better way to implement this sort of "case/switch" function logic that postgres can more readily plan around?

Comment: Try implementing it as a `language SQL` (not `plpgsql`) function, which may get inlined and then benefit from the plans for the called function(s)

Comment: @Bergi is such a thing possible for switching between arbitrary queries?  If so, this would be an excellent solution.

Comment: Also, @Bergi are you suggesting that the plpgsql switch will NOT benefit from the plans for the called functions?

Comment: I am not seeing how it would make a difference in your case: `SELECT * FROM test_tab1(or 2)` is going to be sequence scan regardless.

Comment: Tbh I'm not quite sure what you mean by "*Since the DB presumably can plan for `test_tab1_func`, and it can plan for `test_tab2_func`, can I count on the DB to use those plans for `test_func`?*" in the first place. I would expect that the plans for the statements in the function are made when the function is called, and it doesn't matter if the functions are called from another function or somewhere else.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver well, I've tried to create a minimal reproducible example here.  In my actual use case, the individual SQL functions that I am switching between involve various `JOIN`s and `WHERE`s and `INDEX`es on, amongst other things, postgis `GEOMETRY` columns etc etc etc.  Unfortunately, there is a tension between providing a minimal reproducible example and illustrating the full complexity of the problem.  If you have suggestions for improving my example, I am open to that.

Comment: @Bergi "I would expect" is this the case though?  If you have some reason besides your gut to believe this, then I would upvote and possibly accept such an answer.

Comment: @Him No, but I don't have a reason to believe otherwise either. I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting, that the statements in the function are planned only once, like when the function is defined? What exactly do you expect to go wrong, what does "*use those plans*" refer to?

Comment: Well an example that shows a query that could possibly resolve to something other then a sequence scan.

Comment: @Bergi here is [one of many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27100279/2886575) instances across StackOverflow suggesting that plpgsql functions may block efficient planning.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think that maybe by this you mean to ask for an example that shows a circumstance where the plpgsql function uses a different plan than the "unwrapped" function.  Since my question is essentially about whether or not this is even possible, I must admit that I am not entirely sure how to devise such an example.  If you have such an example, then that would actually be an excellent answer to the question, and I would upvote it and consider accepting it.

Comment: @Bergi "what does 'use those plans' refer to?" This is a good point.  I will try to be more clear.

Comment: @Him I can think of two ways where this would be relevant: a) if you had `test_tab2_func(foo)` and the query plan might (not) be created depending on the value of the argument, and b) if you had `SELECT * FROM test_func() WHERE field1 = 5`, i.e. where the query plan might (not) take into account the filtering by `field1`. I can make some guesses as to whether it will, but I don't know, so I'm curious about an answer myself. (Unfortunately `EXPLAIN` does not show what's happening inside a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I count on a simple case/switch plpgsql function to use a sane query plan?

**Yes**, you can always count on "sane" query plans - in plain SQL or nested in any function. It's always the same query planner, just called from a different context. An "insane" query plan would be cause for a bug report to the PostgreSQL Bug List <pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org> - after making sure the insanity wasn't all yours.

**No**, you cannot count on ***a*** sane query plan, since every nested SQL statement in a function gets its own plan - unless the function is [**inlined**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) as a whole, which is only possible for SQL functions (`LANGUAGE sql`) that fulfill a couple of conditions. So not applicable to PL/pgSQL functions.

Your call results in one plan for the calling `SELECT * FROM test_func();` and another, separate (nested) plan for `SELECT * FROM test_tab1_func();`.
`SELECT * FROM test_tab2_func();` in the other leg of the `IF` construct is not planned at all until control actually reaches it.

To inspect every detail of what's happening behind the curtains, use `auto_explain`. It's simple, but you must be **superuser**. See:

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23357/3684)

Related:

- [LANGUAGE SQL vs LANGUAGE plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/language-sql-vs-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

#### Your example

Splitting into distinct queries along user input **can** make sense if that results in a more efficient query plan for at least one branch. But that's not the case for your simple example, where the added overhead far outweighs the possible gain.

Your function `test_func()` and call can be replaced with plain SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM test_tab1_func() WHERE $foo IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM test_tab2_func() WHERE $foo IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Is the plpgsql statement planned every time it is executed, or is the plan cached? Also for multiple calls to the function?

Comment: @Bergi: Plans can be cached per session, like for prepared statements. More details in [the answer I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860).

Answer (score 1):

Your example updated to include a difference in outcomes for the functions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tab1(
    field1 serial PRIMARY KEY,
    field2 int
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tab2(
    field1 serial PRIMARY KEY,
    field2 int
);

INSERT INTO test_tab1(field2) SELECT  FLOOR(RANDOM()*100000000) FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,1000000);
INSERT INTO test_tab2 SELECT * FROM test_tab1;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_tab1_func()
    RETURNS SETOF test_tab1
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE 
    AS $$
        SELECT * FROM test_tab1 where field1 = 11;
    $$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_tab2_func()
    RETURNS SETOF test_tab1
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE 
    AS $$
        SELECT * FROM test_tab2 where field1 < 100000;
    $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(foo int DEFAULT null)
    RETURNS SETOF test_tab1
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE 
    AS $$
        BEGIN
            IF (foo IS null) THEN
                RETURN QUERY
                SELECT * FROM test_tab1_func();
            ELSE
                RETURN QUERY
                SELECT * FROM test_tab2_func();
            END IF;
        END;
$$;

EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) SELECT * FROM test_func();
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on public.test_func  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.375..0.376 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: field1, field2
   Function Call: test_func(NULL::integer)
 Planning Time: 0.043 ms
 Execution Time: 0.957 ms

EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) SELECT * FROM test_func(1);
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on public.test_func  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=99.505..159.962 rows=999999 loops=1)
   Output: field1, field2
   Function Call: test_func(1)
 Planning Time: 0.016 ms
 Execution Time: 185.767 ms
```

Adding `VERBOSE` and `ANALYZE` shows that Postgres differentiates between the two functions and tracks what running each function on it's own does:

```
EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) SELECT * FROM test_tab1_func();
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using test_tab1_pkey on public.test_tab1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: test_tab1.field1, test_tab1.field2
   Index Cond: (test_tab1.field1 = 11)
 Planning Time: 0.055 ms
 Execution Time: 0.014 ms
(5 rows)

EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) SELECT * FROM test_tab2_func();
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.test_tab2  (cost=0.00..16925.00 rows=999999 width=8) (actual time=0.005..74.222 rows=999999 loops=1)
   Output: test_tab2.field1, test_tab2.field2
   Filter: (test_tab2.field1 < 1000000)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.070 ms
 Execution Time: 96.227 ms
```

Comment: This is unfortunate.  Is there a better way to handle a switch, or is this a currently unavoidable limitation of the query planner?